# PHP fetch_assoc close in a returning function - Scope

Tags: php, scope

Let's say we have a PHP file that calls a returning function

```
function foo(){
    ...
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row;
}
```

If I want to do `$result->close();`, in what scope would I call the `close()`? Putting it after the return statement would make it unreachable code, correct?

If the `$result` is a local variable to `foo()`, is it possible to call `$result->close()` from outside of the function scope (i.e. the global scope after the `foo()` call)?

Normally, I would think to put the values from `$result` into another variable, then call `$result->close()`, then return the temp variable, but this does not appear to work.

Is PHP `fetch_assoc` using pointers or something similar when `$tmp = $result;` then `$result->close()`, it will also close `$tmp`?

What is the best way to handle closing the `$result` variable and returning the values from within it?

Comment: $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
The above code snippet is already a returned array of the result.

Also the close is used on $mysqli->close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to persist `$result`? Just close it right away:

```
function foo(){
    ...
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $result->close();
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing in my Duh moment.